# Data não fica em "branco" sql-srv

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Possuo uma coluna no banco de dados tipo `date`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu altero alguma data em um form `php` e deixo em branco a mesma invés de ficar em branco ela me trás está data de `1900-01-01`.

Abaixo o input que uso para alterar a data.

Data Saída:

```
<input type="date" id="saida" name="saida" value="<?php echo $datasaida; ?>"/>
```

Creio que seja no banco o problema. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Amigo que se você setou o campo no banco com algum tipo que corresponde a uma data e você não envia uma data válida, ele vai trazer o default, que não é algo nulo ou branco, no Mysql se fizer o que está fazendo ele vai trazer 1969-01-01

Comment: Entendi, não tem algum jeito de remediar isso ?

Comment: Remendar nunca é a melhor opção, o certo e corrigir. Pode definir o campo como NULL. NULL é diferente de vazio, você terá que tratar isso no PHP e dizer ao SQL que quer deixar o campo sem valor.

Comment: Ja ajustei, e também no meu `get` eu fiz uma condição `if` quando a data for **01-01-1970** ele não mostra nada se não ele mostra a data.

Comment: Você pode setar o campo com um valor padrão, ou seja, quando não for gravar nada nele, o campo irá assumir o valor padrão, é a melhor opção para você, ao invés de ficar comparando strings.

Comment: Certo, mas eu não quero nem um valor quero que fique sem nada. Quer por essa resposta de setar um valor padrão coloque para mim ver se fica viável.

Comment: Olá Kevin! Você poderia editar a questão com o script para criação da tabela? Verifique se a coluna está configurada para aceitar nulo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você envia um campo vazio o SQL Server não compreende o que você deseja, logo ele coloca uma data por default.

Você tem duas saídas ao meu ver nesse momento.

1) Realizar um teste na sua aplicação, quando o campo estiver em branco, solicitar ao usuário que preencha esse campo

2) Se mesmo assim, desejar o campo em branco, basta **SET NULL** no momento do insert.

Veja se isso aqui te ajuda a compreender melhor:

[SQL Server inserting Date as 1/1/1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070859/sql-server-inserting-date-as-1-1-1900)